# ChoiceBlock consisting of other Wagtail blocks?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I'm trying to construct the carousel `model`:

```
class Carousel(blocks.StructBlock):
    heading = blocks.CharBlock(required=False)
    carousel = blocks.ListBlock(
        blocks.StructBlock([
            ('slide', blocks.StreamBlock([
                ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
                ('video', EmbedBlock())]),
             ),
            ('description', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ])
    )
```

Every slide consists of one image or video and a description.

I'm using `StreamBlock` in here because I couldn't find any other more suitable structural block type which would allow to the user to choose between image and video. Ideally I need something similar to the `ChoiceBlock`, except that the `choices` argument should expect other block types.

Is that feasible? Or at least is there a way to limit how many `sub-blocks` might be inserted from within the `StreamBlock`?

Comment: Why not make the `carousel` ListBlock into a StreamBlock where the two options are 'image' (a StructBlock consisting of ImageChooserBlock + RichTextBlock) and 'video' (a StructBlock consisting of EmbedBlock + RichTextBlock)?

Comment: @gasman Thank you, it seems not too bad alternative. But in general, to solve the problem in the way I described it, do you think it's not feasible?

Comment: There's no dedicated block type for choosing one block from a set. You can set `max_num=1` on StreamBlock, but the UI for that is a bit ugly...